# Render a 3d viewport and save using Python

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, 3d-view

I need to render a 3d viewport and save it. I use this command
`bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True)`
but this option not work `'use_viewport = True'`

I run
[image: I run]

I get a blank image and no rendered viewport
[image: I receive but its no render viewport]

Answer (score 3):

To render a 3D viewport and save the result using the Blender Python API, you can use the following code:

```
import bpy

# Set the output file path
output_file = "C:/path/to/output.png"

# Set the viewport resolution
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1080

# Set the output format
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"

# Render the viewport and save the result
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
bpy.data.images["Render Result"].save_render(output_file)
```

This code will render the current viewport and save the result to the specified output file. The `bpy.ops.render.render()` method takes several optional parameters, including `use_viewport` which determines whether to use the current viewport or the camera view for the rendering. However, this parameter is not necessary when rendering the viewport, as it is the default behavior of the render operator.

To learn more about the render operator and the other parameters it accepts, you can refer to the [Blender Python API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html)